# How to check whether the complete Div is valid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation

I have a HTML like this.

```css
input:valid {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
.customInput {
  border: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  width: 105px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="personalInfo" class="info active">
  <div class="elementContainers">
    <span class="labelText ">First Name</span>
    <span class="spacing"></span>
    <input type="text" class="customInput" id="firstName" name="firstName" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,}" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="elementContainers">
    <span class="labelText">Last Name</span>
    <span class="spacing"></span>
    <input type="text" class="customInput" id="lastName" name="lastName" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,}" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="elementContainers">
    <span class="labelText ">Gender</span>
    <span class="spacing"></span>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M">Male
    <span class="spacing"></span>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F">Female
  </div>
  <div class="elementContainers">
    <span class="labelText"> Date of Birth</span>
    <span class="spacing"></span>
    <input type="text" class="customInput datepicker" name="actualDOB" required pattern=".{6,}" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I have used the HTML5 pattern attribute to validate the fields.
Individually I can check whether the corresponding field is valid or not.

like this:

```
$('#firstName:valid').length
```

It will return me 1 if valid, 0 unless.

I need to check whether the `div#personalInfo` is valid or not.
How can I check this, except looping through all the elements and checking?

Comment: I think you'd need to verify each of them since they are child to your `#personalInfo`

Comment: Using custom validation you can do that, try using Jquery validation plugin. In  custom validation you can assign a error class to the div in case of error.

Answer (score 2):

**Currently** with CSS there is no way to send CSS to parent objects without some javascript magic.

I am sorry :-(

CSS only allows you to change child elements (or sibling elements) of an individual node.

---

If you *do* want to use jquery to check validity of your child elements you can do:

```
$('#personalInfo :valid').length; // gives you the size of the valid input objects
```

Which does a query for all child elements of `#personalInfo` that are valid.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 has a [built-in method](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-form-checkvalidity) `checkValidity()` which checks a `form` element and returns whether its constraint validation is positive or negative. The [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation) for this method is adopted by most major vendors so use when appropriate.

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/dunugopini/edit?html,js,output)